# What is the best DVR application for Windows (7)?

Tags: dvr, dvr-ms

I've been unable to find very little credible or up to date information on DVR platforms for Windows. I'm looking for the best out there (under $200) that provides TiVo like quality (season passes, responsive FF/RW, etc).

Any thoughts guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Should probably be CW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_PVR_software_packages) for a comparison of features.

Of the ones listed, I know the following support Windows 7 (either officially or unofficially):

- Windows Media Center
- XBMC
- Beyond TV
- GB-PVR

I've personally used MediaPortal. It works great and has a good set of features. Unfortunately   it has issues with Windows 7 right now so I can't recommend it for your scenario.

Other than Windows Media Center, I've not seen a dvr/pvr application that supports 64-bit versions of Windows. Although, MediaPortal, being a .NET application should theoretically run as a 64-bit application it doesn't on my Vista 64-bit system. This shouldn't really be a determining factor as many of these applications run just fine under WoW64.

Comment: I have used BeyondTV for years.  It's good for scheduling shows to record and watching them later.  It's horrific for watching live tv as it buffers up about 6 seconds of time before showing, so any channel changes, etc are delayed a few seconds after you make the change.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say Windows Media Center, [MythTV on Windows](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythTV_on_Windows) or [GBPVR](http://www.gbpvr.com/).

I do not know, or have every compared any commercial DVR applications (other than Windows Media Center).

Windows Media Center is probably my favourite, it is well polished and is generally very good.

MythTV, Very complicated to configure on anything other than the prebuilt Linux editions such as [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/), but works very well.

GBVPR, I have never used this, but been hearing more and more about it recently.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using Media Center at home for a couple of years, and I really don't have any issues with it.  We used Myth for a couple of years prior to that, and had constant issues.  We'd figured getting good Hauppage cards would make the difference, but we never had any luck.  It probably had a lot to do with not being very strong with linux and not having much time to learn it, so unless you are - I'd stick with easier stuff.